# Thread-per-request tcp server

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I am just trying to understand how to write a thread-per-request TCP server in Java.
I have already written a thread-per-connection server, that runs serverSocket.accept() and creates a new thread each time a new connection comes in.

How could this be modified into a thread-per-request server?
I suppose the incoming connections could be put into some sort of queue, but how would you know which one has issued a request & is ready for service?

I am suspecting that NIO is necessary here, but not sure.

Thanks.

[edit]

To be clear - The original "server" is just a loop that I have written that waits for a connection and then passes it to a new thread.

The lecturer has mentioned "thread-per-request" architecture, and I was wondering how it worked "under the hood".

My first idea about how it works, may be completely wrong.

Comment: You do not provide nearly enough information. Exactly how your original server can be modified into a thread-per-request server is unanswerable as we have no idea how your original server is implemented or what the nature of it is. For all we know it's just a matter of changing per-connection" to "per-request" in a configuration file somewhere. Please show your code, describe the problem you are having, the expected and actual results, and what steps you've taken to try and solve it.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you think NIO is related; you need to figure out *what* you're trying to do before you try and guess what tools you should do it with.

Comment: Why? What benefit are you hoping to obtain? How are you going to get more than one request at a time per connection? Question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The  server is just a loop I have written myself, that accepts a connection and hands it to a new thread. Why am I trying to create one thread per request? To learn.

Comment: To learn what?  Real servers aren't written that way.

Comment: Ok. My lecturer has mentioned "thread per request architecture" where new threads are only created when a request comes in, not when a connection comes in. I am just wondering, how would such a server work under the hood? Does it necessarily have to use NIO?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Selector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) to achieve your goal. [Here](http://www.studytrails.com/java-io/non-blocking-io-multiplexing.jsp) is a good example you can refer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain IO, or blocking NIO, (OR non-blocking NIO, or async NIO2)  You can have any multiple threads per connection (or a shared worker thread pool) but unless these are waiting for slow services like databases, this might be any faster (it can be much slower if you want low latency)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you be able to explain how plain IO can be used to create a thread-per-request architecture?